I need to build a query in Oracle SQL such that it should fetch records with only null ornnn_id
From this data:
ornnn_id   ind_id   effect_from_dat
3574953     null    null
3574953     null    null
3574953     null    null    
3574953     null    null    
3574953     null    null
3574953     null    null
3574953     null    null
3574953     1       08-AUG-2003 10.20.10
3574953     1       08-AUG-2003 10.20.10
3574953     1       08-AUG-2003 10.20.10
3574953     1       08-AUG-2003 10.20.10
3574953     1       08-AUG-2003 10.20.10
12345      null     null
12345      null     null
1212       3        08-AUG-2003 10.20.10
1212       3        08-AUG-2003 10.20.10

I need to query such that only records with null ind_id and effect_from_dat are fetched eg the row with ornnn_id 12345
My query
select ornnn_id, ind_id,sl_effect_from_dat from table where sl_ind is null and sl_effect_from_dat is null

is fetching ornnn_id 3574953 and 12345 - but I only want 12345.


So... have a where clause that checks that each of those columns is null? What problem do you have - have you written a query that doesn't work?

select ornnn_id, ind_id,sl_effect_from_dat from table   where sl_ind is null and sl_effect_from_dat is null this query is fetching ornnn_id 3574953 and 12345.  What I want is query to fetch only 12345

query need to exclude ornnn_id even if one ind_id and effect_from_dat record is present

And here's another way if you don't need to return the duplicate rows but rather just one row. You didn't specify if you need both rows as they are identical. This query calls the table just once.

There are a few ways to do this, depending on what output you want; here are a couple:
select ornnn_id
from your_table
group by ornnn_id
having max(ind_id) is null
and max(effect_from_dat) is null




ORNNN_ID




12345



That just gets the unique IDs - the other columns seems pointless as you know they are null; but if you want them you can change the first line to:
select ornnn_id, null as ind_id, null as effect_from_dat

or
select ornnn_id, max(ind_id) as ind_id, max(effect_from_dat) as effect_from_dat

Or this gets all the rows if you don't just want the unique IDs:
select ornnn_id, ind_id, effect_from_dat
from your_table t1
where ind_id is null
and effect_from_dat is null
and not exists (
  select null
  from your_table t2
  where t2.ornnn_id = t1.ornnn_id
  and (t2.ind_id is not null or t2.effect_from_dat is not null)
)




ORNNN_ID
IND_ID
EFFECT_FROM_DAT




12345
null
null


12345
null
null



fiddle
There are others, like MT0's analytic count. It depends what you actually want, and how the various approaches perform with your data.

You can use the analytic COUNT function and look for a count of zero in both (since COUNT(column_name) does not count NULL values)
SELECT ornnn_id,
       ind_id,
       sl_effect_from_dat
FROM   (
  SELECT ornnn_id,
         ind_id,
         sl_effect_from_dat,
         COUNT(ind_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ornnn_id) AS num_ind_id,
         COUNT(sl_effect_from_dat) OVER (PARTITION BY ornnn_id) AS num_sl_effect_from_dat
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_ind_id = 0
AND    num_sl_effect_from_dat = 0;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (ornnn_id, ind_id, sl_effect_from_dat) AS
SELECT 3574953, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, 1, DATE '2023-08-08' + INTERVAL '10:20:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, 1, DATE '2023-08-08' + INTERVAL '10:20:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, 1, DATE '2023-08-08' + INTERVAL '10:20:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, 1, DATE '2023-08-08' + INTERVAL '10:20:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3574953, 1, DATE '2023-08-08' + INTERVAL '10:20:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12345, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12345, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1212, 3, DATE '2023-08-08' + INTERVAL '10:20:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1212, 3, DATE '2023-08-08' + INTERVAL '10:20:10' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ORNNN_ID
IND_ID
SL_EFFECT_FROM_DAT




12345
null
null


12345
null
null



fiddle
